# I need make array of streamreader

Tags: c#, arrays, file, merge, streamreader

I want to list multiple files in a directory, and I need to merge every 10 files.

```
public static void MergeFiles (string pathSource)
{
    DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(pathSource);
    FileInfo[] Arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles("*.*");            
    int i = 0;

    foreach (FileInfo file in Arquivos)
    {
        StreamReader[] writer = **new StreamReader();** //'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
        writer[i] = File.OpenText(diretorio + file.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(writer.Count());
        i++;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: At least you should somehow define order of files you want to merge in. Or you want to merge every 10 arbitrary choosen files?

Comment: +1. SO's becoming slightly over-pedantic recently. He might not have asked this in the clearest of ways, but he's showing his attempt and own effort.

Comment: I don´t know how I make a array of StreamReader.
Look the error: 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Well have you looked at the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) to see what constructor to use?

Comment: @PedroKuramoto creating arrays is already covered in many questions on SO and MSDN articles. You may want to check [Array Tutorial C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN to clarify what you have problem with. Possibly your question is "what is the difference between creating an array and initializing elements of the array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is fixed size, and should be initialized as follows (please don't call a *reader* "writer"):

```
// Size of 10
StreamReader[] writer = new StreamReader[10];
```

Also you are creating the array *inside* the loop, meaning there will be one array *per file*. Create the array outside of the loop:

```
StreamReader[] writer = new StreamReader[10];
foreach (FileInfo file in Arquivos)
{
    ...
```

You may consider using a `List<StreamReader>` so if you have say 25 files, you would be able to merge 10, 10 and finally the remaining 5 files:

```
List<StreamReader> readers = new List<StreamReader>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Arquivos)
{
    readers.Add(File.OpenText(diretorio + file.Name));
    if (readers.Count >= 10)
    {
        MergeFiles(readers);
        readers.Clear();
    }
}

// Optionally handle the last bunch
if (readers.Count > 0)
{
    MergeFiles(readers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StreamReader[] writer = new StreamReader[10];
foreach (FileInfo file in Arquivos)
{

    writer[i] = File.OpenText(diretorio + file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(writer.Count());
    i++;
}
```